# Struggling with angular $promise and asynchronous response from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an angular service which is basically a wrapper for another service that makes $resource requests for json data. This 'wrapper service' does some data formatting and then returns the result to my controller.

My problem is that I am struggling to populate my $scope variable (always undefined) in my controller from the function in the 'wrapper' service I have created. I have tried a little with the Deferred API, but I can only successfully get my data in the controller if I call the promise.then method in my controller(without formatting it) which defeats the purpose.

How do I return a formatted list to my controller? I have written a Plunker below which doesn't compile but contains the gist of what I am trying to achieve.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AGyyqvawpnBmKXTcvGkJ?p=info

Comment: If the plunker doesn't work, how can we figure out what if a problem exists in your code or just in the plunker?

Comment: instead of using a factor have you tried a service?    From: routingRulesServices.factory('RuleSets'        To: routingRulesServices.service('RuleSets'

Comment: Hi Anthony Chu, I understand it's tough to work with a code sample that doesn't compile, but I believed my issue was a fundamental lack of understanding, so I was sure that someone could assist, which Wawy was able to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult without being able to compile the plunkr, but could you tell me if this works:

factory.js:

```
routingRulesHelper.factory('ruleSetQueryWrapper', ['$q','RuleSets',

function($q, RuleSets) {
    var formatResults = function (ruleSet) {

        var aRuleSchedule = {};

        //format the payload to correct data ...........

        return aRuleSchedule;
    };
    return {
        getRuleSetById: function(ruleSetId){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var ruleset = RuleSets.query({ruleSetId: ruleSetId}, function(ruleSet) {
                deferred.resolve(formatResults(ruleSet));

            }, function(response) {
                //404 or bad
                if(response.status === 404) {
                    console.log("HTTP Error", response.status);
                }
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
}}]);
```

controller.js:

```
routingRulesControllers.controller('RulesDisplayCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'RuleSets', 'ruleSetQueryWrapper',
function($scope, $location, $routeParams, RuleSets, ruleSetQueryWrapper) {

    $scope.formattedResults = null;

    if($routeParams.ruleSetId) {
         ruleSetQueryWrapper.getRuleSetById($routeParams.ruleSetId).then(function(results) {
          $scope.formattedResults = results;
         });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I agree with this, user1027339 is trying to resolve the promise inside his service he should return the promise and resolve it inside the controller as shown

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you. The result is fairly obvious once one looks at it, but I need to get my level of understanding up when it comes to asynchronous data and deferred / promise API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should instead of this

`deferred.resolve(ruleSet)`

do

`deferred.resolve(formatResults(ruleset))`

also you are not returning the deferred.promise in the `getRuleSetById` service method.

Comment: thank you for your idea. It was correct too, but I was just missing some logic in my controller which the answer by Wawy helped me with